# One to many mapping in mule data mapper

Tags: mule

[image]I have an input xml and it has only one `Telephone` child element,

```
<ContactMethod>
                <Telephone type="fax">
                    <Number>String</Number>
                    <Extension>String</Extension>
                </Telephone>
</ContactMethod>
```

But my output XML has multiple `Telephone` child element,

```
<ContactMethod>
                    <Telephone type="fax">
                        <Number>String</Number>
                        <Extension>String</Extension>
                    </Telephone>
                    <Telephone type="fax">
                        <Number>String</Number>
                        <Extension>String</Extension>
                    </Telephone>
    </ContactMethod>
```

I want to map from input element `Number` to output `Number` and also `Extension` element.

I can't change the schema because it is globally used.

I don't see any options to map using `Element Mapping`.

And I tried using adding `Rule` to the `ContactMethod` element, but no luck.

......

Above I is just example I asked. I need one to many mapping idea in `datamapper`.

See attached image, that is my actual requirement. Look at the `Disclosure/CandidateDisclosure` elements in source and destination

My source is XML and target is JSON, but the actual logic I need is similar for all the structures ..

Comment: Can you review your snippets? it looks like you just want to duplicate the input

Comment: My source is xml and target is json.. Just for understanding I explained both are xml.

Answer (score 0):

I am maintaining a project which use DataMapper and faced the same issue. To solve it I add Java Transformer (you can use Groovy or other scripting languages) after DataMapper to group the one-to-many relationship.

Following is the pseudo code:

```
 provide empty telpMap

 foreach telpXml which is extracted from src/payload {
     key = telpXml.get("@type");
     if (telpMap.containsKey(key)) {
         List number = telpMap.get(key).get("Number");
         number.addAll(telpXml.get("Number"));
         List extension = telpMap.get(key).get("Extension");
         extension.addAll(telpXml.get("Extension"));
     } else {
         telpMap.put(key, telpXml);
     }
 }

 return telpMap.values();
```